# nginx configuration not redirecting 80-->443 although valid

Tags: ssl, nginx

Why is the following `nginx.conf` not redirecting when I am accessing my site on `http://my-domain-name.com` ?

```
root@atlantis-server:~# cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {


    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name atlantis_server;
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {

     server_name atlantis_server;
     listen 443 ssl;


    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_certificate     /root/certs/atlantis-server/some.cer.b64;
    ssl_certificate_key /root/certs/atlantis-server/some.key;
    ssl_ciphers         EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;   



    }
}
```

Access on `https://my-domain-name.com` is done properly!

Comment: I'm not sure where you get **atlantic_server**, have you checked your syntax is correct with this command `sudo nginx -t`

Comment: `root@atlantis-server:~# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`

Comment: atlantis_server` is just my server name; should there be a corresponding entry somewhere else?

Comment: seem correct, can you try like this.
```server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.your-server.com your-server.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> may be try to this code

```
server {
      listen [::]:80;
      listen 80;
      server_name my-domain-name.com www.my-domain-name.com ;

      # redirect http to https www
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
```